# Criteria API - advantage of having parameter expressions

Tags: java, performance, criteria, criteria-api

What is the advantage of having parameter expressions in criteria api query?

```
ParameterExpression<String> myParameter= criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class, "name");
criteriaBuilder.equal(someDatabaseColumn,myParameter);
query.setParameter(myParameter,"valueOfParameter");
```

or

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(someDatabaseColumn,"valueOfParameter");
```

Both the ways, the result is same. But, what is the impact on performance of query with or without using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically change your queries without risking security (SQL injection). Also, it allows you to have "loosely coupled" code by designing a a more generic approach to your logic, instead of writing specific SQL queries on strings. You will not get any performance advantage unless your queries are precompiled (Queries defined in the entity with `@NamedQueries`).